# mass replace specific lines in file using bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with the name file.txt and contents

```
$cat file.txt
this one
juice apple
orange pen
apple
rice
mouse
```

and I have another file called word.txt

```
$cat word.txt
ganti
buah
bukan
```

i want to replace line 1,3 and 5 in file.txt with word.txt using bash. so the final result in file.txt becomes:

```
$cat file.txt
ganti
juice apple
buah
apple
bukan
mouse
```

how to use bash to do this operation? thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried using sed. `cat line.txt word.txt | while read line.txt word.txt; do sed -i '${line.txt}s/.*/${word.txt}/' file.txt; done`

Comment: but it didn't work. `line.txt` is the line number to be replaced

Comment: Please add your code to the question not as comment. You probably need to show the contents of `line.txt` too, and explain how the code is supposed to match up data from different files. Presumably the malay is just for the example? otherwise it is unclear why a pen becomes buah but apple doesn't, or how bukan relates to rice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you're trying to do, is this the end result you're after?

```
# read the 'word.txt' lines into an array called "words"
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a words < word.txt

# create a 'counter'
iter=0

# for loop through the line numbers that you want to change
for i in 1 3 5
do
    # the variable "from" is the line from 'file.txt' (e.g. 1, 3, or 5)
    from="$(sed -n ""$i"p" file.txt)"
    # the variable "to" is the index/iteration of 'word.txt' (e.g. 1, 2, or 3)
    to=${words[$iter]}
    # make the 'inline' substitution
    sed -i "s/$from/$to/g" file.txt
    # increase the 'counter' by 1
    ((iter++))
done

cat file.txt
ganti
juice apple
buah
apple
bukan
mouse
```

### Edit

If you have the line numbers you want to change in a file called "line.txt", you can adjust the code to suit:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a words < word.txt

iter=0

while read -r line_number
do
    from="$(sed -n ""$line_number"p" file.txt)"
    to=${words[$iter]}
    sed -i "s/$from/$to/g" file.txt
    ((iter++))
done < line.txt

cat file.txt
ganti
juice apple
buah
apple
bukan
mouse
```

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ed` to read first `file.txt` and then `word.txt` and shuffle lines of the latter around and finally save the modified `file.txt`:

```sh
ed -s file.txt <<EOF
0r word.txt
4d
2m5
4d
2m6
5d
w
EOF
```

`m` commands move lines, and `d` commands delete lines.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# the 1st argument is the word.txt file
# remaining arguments are the line numbers to replace in ascending order
# assign the patterns file to file descriptor 3
exec 3< "$1"
shift

# read the first replacement pattern
read -ru 3 replacement
current_line_number=1

# lines will be read from standard in
while read -r line; do
    # for replacement lines with a non-empty replacement str...
    if [ "$current_line_number" == "$1" -a -n "$replacement" ]; then
        echo "$replacement"
        read -ru 3 replacement # get the next pattern
        shift # get the next replacement line number
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
    (( current_line_number++ ))
done
```

To test

```sh
diff expect <(./replace-lines.sh word.txt 1 3 5 < file.txt) && echo ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `ed` approach, with Process substitution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s file.txt < <(
  printf '%s\n' '1s|^|1s/.*/|' '2s|^|3s/.*/|' '3s|^|5s/.*/|' ',s|$|/|' '$a' ,p Q . ,p Q |
  ed -s word.txt
)
```